# I am new to flutter web, how to authenticate users using firebase phone authentication, is there a way to keep user logged in?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, flutter-web

Here's a basic code for sign-in using firebase phone authentication, which can be understood from basic flutter-fire documentation, which doesn't explain practically how to implement firebase phone authentication in flutter web. Flutter Native mobile phone authentication is easy :)

Also, how to remember the signed user for certain days?

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

ConfirmationResult confirmationResult = await auth.signInWithPhoneNumber('+44 7123 123 456');

UserCredential userCredential = await confirmationResult.confirm('123456');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users automatically stay signed in to Firebase. To pick up the user's authentication state when the app is restarted, check the documentation on [authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/#authentication-state), which has this handy example:

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Also see the answer I just gave to: [Anonymous User not detecting by firebase code error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279694/anonymous-user-not-detecting-by-firebase-code-error/66280700#66280700)

Comment: Hey Frank, do I need to use firebase_auth or firebase_auth_web package for the web app?