# Anonymous User not detecting by firebase code error

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add anonymous user functionality and save this to device for further usage, but whenever I restart my app firebase not detecting if currentUser is Anonymous and it was working like 3-5 days ago perfectly.

**Anonymous Login Code**

```dart
signInAnonymously().then((value) async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  preferences.setString(
    'name',
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid
  );
  preferences.setBool('anon', true);
});
```

**Main Code**

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
    
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  var name = prefs.getString('name');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Algolia algolia = Application.algolia;
  print(auth.currentUser.isAnonymous); // Returns false even if i logged anonymously before
  runApp(ThemeProvider(
    saveThemesOnChange: true,
    themes: [
      AppTheme(
        id: 'white',
        data: constant.whiteTheme,
        description: 'white theme'
      ),
      AppTheme(
        id: 'dark',
        data: constant.darkTheme,
        description: 'dark theme'
      ),
    ],
    child: ThemeConsumer(
      child: Builder(
        builder: (themeContext) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: name == null
             ? OnBoardScreen(
                 algolia: algolia,
               )
             : WelcomeScreen(
                 isAnon: prefs.getBool('anon'),
                 algolia: algolia,
             ),
            theme: ThemeProvider.themeOf(themeContext).data,
          );
        }),
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

**Main Code**

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
 
  print(auth.currentUser.uid); //returns UID of anon user
  print(auth.currentUser.isAnonymous);//returns false all the time
```

**Log Of Main Code**

```
I/flutter (31830): ci90IxegpvMyq0vGqhtHxqcrrT52
I/flutter (31830): false
```

So I can print UID of my anonymous user but isAnonymous state still returns false.

*Note*: I know that I can handle user situations with SharedPreferences, but what is causing this? And can't I get if user is logged in anonymously before restarting app with "FirebaseAuth"?

**SOLVE**

Problem solved with wiping data and using new emulator.

Answer (score 1):

When you restart the app, Firebase has to check whether the user still has access (for example: you may have disabled their account). This is an asynchronous operation, since it requires a call to the server and may take some time to complete.

When your code accesses `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`, this asynchronous call may not have completed yet - leading to `currentUser` still being `null`.

To be certain that you always respond to the correct authentication state, use an auth state listener as shown in the documentation on [authentication state](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage#authentication-state):

```
FirebaseAuth.instance
  .authStateChanges()
  .listen((User user) {
    if (user == null) {
      print('User is currently signed out!');
    } else {
      print('User is signed in!');
    }
  });
```

Comment: I can print currentUser.uid which gives me UID of an anonymous user, but still currentUser.isAnonymous  returns false,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66281219/firebase-auth-signinanonymously-bug This question is more clear actually

Comment: If I answered the wrong question and you want to clarify your question, edit *this* post please and don't create a new question

Comment: I edited this question with my main code and log of my code for clarification of my question and no you didn't answer the wrong question